# Retrieve details of Airplay devices

Tags: macos, airplay

I've got an unknown Airplay device on a network that keeps showing up as "Apple TV" on my Mac and iPhone. I don't want to connect to it, but I would like to get some details on it (ideally a MAC address and/or IP address.) Is there a CLI utility buried in MacOS that I can use to enumerate Airplay devices and get more detail on them?

Comment: This is a bit broad - what you’re looking for can be obtained from the router/DHCP server lease table, or by issuing the command `arp -a` and looking for the AppleTV in the results.

Comment: Looking through an ARP table doesn't help if I have neither an IP or MAC address to look for. It's intermittent and I'm not sure if there's something cached or what. To the best of my knowledge, I've never ever connected to an Apple TV. And AFAIK AirPlay is not routed, but there is not an Apple TV on my subnet.

Comment: You can also try pinging the broadcast address to “scan” your subnet.  Eg.  `ping 192.168.1.255` you can get the broadcast address by issuing the command `ifconfig en0` (or `en1` depending on how you’re connected to your network